# Jar file not using custom font

Tags: java, truetype, resource-loading

Inside NetBeans my custom font loads properly from this set of code but fails to load when I run my program from the executable jar file

code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arcanus arc = new Arcanus();  
    try {
        Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Golden-Sun.ttf")).deriveFont(12f);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Golden-Sun.ttf")));
        arc.setFont(customFont);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

any help would be apreciated

Comment: Must ask, is your font in your classpath? are you sure?

Comment: what is the exception and where is your file located?

Comment: I dont know how to check an exception when running my program from the jar, also for my font to be in my classpath...where would I put my font?

Comment: You have to load via `getResource()`

Comment: so how would i specially would i write it out

Comment: Downlaod this [file](http://www.fonts2u.com/download/golden-sun-regular.font) and place it in resources folder and create the jar agai

Comment: nvm I got it the issue was I did not have it in my class path..thanks for all who commented appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded resources should *NOT* be read from a `File` object. The `File` object is used for reading files in the local file system. Once your file is jarred, it becomes a resource and should be read as such. You can read it as a `InputStream` by using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`. For example

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Golden-sun.tff");
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

Where `Golden-sun.tff` is on the class path (direct child of `src` for development)

```
Root
   src
      Golden-sun.tff
```

Comment: yea I got it working properly ty for the post though